# array_push() function not working in recursive function

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am using a recursive function in php. The function travers through an array and inputs some values of the array in a new array. I am using `array_push()` to enter values in the new array and I have also tried to do it without using `array_push`. This is the part of the function that calls the recursive function

```
if ($this->input->post('id') != '') {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');

    global $array_ins;
    $k=0;
    $data['condition_array'] = $this->array_check($id, $menus['parents'], $k);

    // trial
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($menus['parents']);
    print_r($data['condition_array']);die;
    // trial
}
```

and this here is the recursive function

```
function array_check($val, $array_main, $k) {
    // echo $val . "<br>";
    $array_ins[$k] = $val;
    echo $k . "<br>";
    $k++;
    // $array_ins = array_push($array_ins, $val);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($array_ins);
    if ($array_main[$val] != '') {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array_main[$val]); $i++) {
            $this->array_check($array_main[$val][$i], $array_main, $k);
        }
        // $k++;
    }
```

I've been trying to fix this erorr for quite some time with no luck . I would really appreciate any help possible .
thanks in advance

Comment: please post sample values from $array_ins

Answer (score 2):

Move the `global $array_ins;` statement into the function.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the variable `$array_ins` as a parameter to function

```
function array_check($val, $array_main, $k,$array_ins) {


}
```

and call the function

```
$this->array_check($id, $menus['parents'], $k,$array_ins);
```

or

```
function array_check($val, $array_main, $k) {

global $array_ins;

}
```

usage of `global` is not recommended in php check it here [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)

Comment: `$array_ins` should be passed by reference, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The global keyword should be used inside of functions so that the variable will refer to the value in the outer scope.

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    global $a, $b;

    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b; // 3
```